# How to justify to ask for the technologies stack of the customer application in precise manner?

Tags: development-process, project-proposal

In my recent project , we have to build a complete system which will work as a client for their system "server" which will consume their API.

our system also have back end and front end to communicatie with their API

so customer demand about our technology Stack on which we will build this system.

now for that we also requirement for the informatiom of their tech stack  so choose the better tool to collaborate while their API consumption.

So My question is how to ask the customer fir their technology Stack in a manner which will describe why we need this but the language I have used is not proper.

kindly suggest me how to ask

here is my version

> I have one request for * team*.
>
> We also need your technology stacks information used to build the your
>   system , such as which java version, web-socket library , database
>   version and typeand other information which will be pre-requisites and
>   API signature or any other constraints.
>
> It would help us to choose the right tool and packages to make better
>   compatibility with their API.

Comment: How will the two systems (the existing one and yours) be deployed? Will they be deployed to the same machines? How well/detailed is the API specified?

Comment: we will deploy may be as a package . but currently we need to fetch their data and display on this system.

Comment: this new system cab be deployed on-premise or it will be used as web apps which will consume their API and later it will be main interface to connect with other systems.( that is not clear yet)

Comment: Is building your stack on their systems an actual project requirement? The whole point of APIs is that they should be relatively platform-agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a checklist for building your client (Requirement list) and have the customer fill it instead of an open question. This will help you focus on the points you need to know and will help the customer to give the right answers. So for example, you'd say:

> Currently we're building the technical requirements for the client system we're buildng and we need your help by filling the attached checklist so that we avoid having a client that's not compatible with the current server.

And it would be nice to have the checklist categorized in a manner that maps to how you design your system. For example:

**Security Management**

- Do you use any authentication to access the server? If so what type and would the API need authentication or will have full access?
- Do you use any open source framework for user management like keyclock or similar?

**Data Management**

- What is the database your using?
- Is there any kind of data cashing used?
- Do you intend to use Nosql database in the future?

**Technology Stack**

- Is there any constraints to use Node.JS
- What's the libraries used to build the server?
- Do you prefer REST or Web services architecture? and why?

**Deployment Flow**

and so on...etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and valuable suggestion also for the categorized pattern checklist.